# Is it correct to say 'I gave off to students'

Tags: expressions

If you are a teacher and you cancel today's class, is it correct to say 'I gave off to students'?

Comment: You could say "I gave the students the day off." or "I gave a day off to the students (today or whenever)."

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd That means something entirely different . . . Certainly not something a teacher should be admitting to.

Comment: @DavidM - ooops must have read it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not correct. The verb to "give off" means to emit something, typically a scent or gas.

Any of the following would be correct:

- I gave the students the day off
- I gave the day off to the students

You could be more specific and say "I gave the students the class off" (although that's an unusual construct) or less specific: "I gave the students time off".